resetField in react hook form doesn't work
If you use the reset method and the resetField method together, the resetField method will not work.
This is an example of not using the reset method.
const { reset, resetField, register } = useForm();


<input {...register("test")} />
<button onClick={() => {resetField("test")}}>button</button>

If you enter a value in input and click the button, the value in input is initialized.
This is an example of using the reset method and resetField method together.
const { reset, resetField, register } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  reset({test: "test"});
}, [])

<input {...register("test")} />
<button onClick={() => {resetField("test")}}>button</button>

When using the reset method and resetField method together, there is an issue that the value is not initialized when the button is clicked.
What should I do?

have you tried <button type='button' ... >?

@pedramafra Thanks for showing me how to do it. However, that method does not work with the desired result.  When using the reset method
keepDefaultValues option to true when using the reset method and it seems to work as desired. I'm still trying to figure out exactly why.
